# What is this SBT command: *lift is org.lifty lifty 1.6.1

Tags: sbt

What is the name of, function of and documentation for the [Simple Build Tool](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simple_Build_Tool) (SBT) command in this example:

```
> *lift is org.lifty lifty 1.6.1
```

This is not a question about `lift` or `lifty`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This registers a new processor in sbt 0.7.7 and earlier.  A processor adds a new command.  See http://code.google.com/p/simple-build-tool/wiki/Processors for documentation.

Note that in 0.10 and later versions, it is no longer called a processor, but is just called a command and is added by normal plugins instead of being a separate extension point.